# Delete text if screen is under 979px wide in bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

Well I have a little problem;
I have some text in my heading that looks like this (979px wide) http://gyazo.com/58ebb51b727b535566d3ce3c4648fc16

And if the user screen is under 979px the text goes like this
http://gyazo.com/04d009c6d4dd97931a989926c1bd94bb

So I need to remove that text if the screen is under 979px

PD : I'm using bootstrap and the heading is built in php

Comment: Google "media queries" possibly with the addition of "bootstrap"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text is in some

Tag like this:

```
<p class="your-text-selector">Some Text</p>
```

Add this to your css file.

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  .your-text-selector {
    display: none;
  }
}
```